# Benefit of convolution with input_hole and mask in image inpainting project

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am studying inpainting on a "damaged" image's project from papers. And I realized that recently people often combine image with hole (3-channel) and mask(1-channel) to be input (they concat to become 4-channel). There is even case where it add (1-mask) image --> it become 5-channel. Then, they use autoencoder to create a "coarse" image.

So, why need to combine them together? And If we concat(image_hole,mask), what benefits will we get?

This is example about mask and image_hole:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: at least reference those papers. why don't you ask the authors? don't they explain why they do things in their papers?

Comment: E.g.: https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07892 and http://iizuka.cs.tsukuba.ac.jp/projects/completion/data/completion_sig2017.pdf
I asked them by email, but no reply for me.